# Count equal lookup values from different nodes. XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, lookup

Count equal lookup values from different nodes. XSLT

Count `<book>` nodes having the same lookup value from a DB table.For every `<code>` I make a search in a DB table to find the corresponding value to that code. This value from the lookup I will save into a variable  Different `<code>` numbers can have the same lookup value(For example: /code=11 and code=12 have the same lookup value in DB table so I have to output 2 .For code=13 I have to output 1.

In the output I have to show the counter for distinct lookup values.

```html
 <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book/code">
  <xsl:variable name="$code" select ="lookup("code","book_code")"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::$code)"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

INPUT :

`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
  <book>
    <code>11</code>
  </book>
  <book>
    <code>12</code>
  </book>
</bookstore>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <code>13</code>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

OUTPUT:
2
1

Comment: Where is that lookup table where "code=11 and code=12 have the same lookup value"? And which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you would want

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="bookstore/book" group-by="key('lookup', code, $lookup-doc)">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I think, using e.g. a key for the second document based on `<xsl:key name="lookup" match="some-element" use="book_code"/>.

You haven't really spelled out details of the second document structure or your pseudo code with `lookup`, so the above can only be adapted to the right key and key call if you show the document structure of the secondary document.